# How to list all packages in a repo by name

Tags: package-management, repository

I've made a full clone of Ubuntu packages repo (about 230 GB), and running a local VM as my repo server.
What command can I use to list ALL packages contained within that repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally (that is, on the server), you can run:

```
find /location/of/repo/ -type f -name '*.deb'
```

Remotely, you can fetch the `Packages` file and grep it:

```
wget -qO - http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz \
  | zgrep -Po '(?<=^Package: ).*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [@muru answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/579074/146791), if you want to find all the available package  in your local 
repo server from a  local Ubuntu system, you can use metadata file of each package resource specified in sources.list which is present in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`.
Only requirement is that your Ubuntu system should be  configured to receive  update from your local server.

For example

```
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/
grep -oP "(?<=Package: ).*" security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages
```

Replace the file  name (i.e. `security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages` ) with your local server file name . Also make sure this list name end with `Packages`.